# Send text with ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, email

I am developing an Android application in which I am sending multiple attachments to email client application.
To send multiple attachments I am using ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE intent.

**Code snippet:**

```
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test"); // email subject

        ArrayList<CharSequence> msg = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
        msg.add(mail_body); // email body
        emailIntent.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);

        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>(); //attachments
        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(logFile));
        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(oldLogFile));
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."), ErrorCodes.MAIL_ACTIVITY);
```

**Output of the above code:**

In the Gmail application, the attachments are present but email body is missing.

How can I fix this issue? I would appreciate any suggestions and thought on this topic.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]. Also, bear in mind that `ACTION_SEND`/`ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` is a *request*, and that different email clients may handle such `Intent` options in different ways (including possibly having bugs).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will add the code snippets.

Comment: Please check the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

First, `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` does not use a `Uri`, as you have with your `setData()` call.

Second, `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` uses *either* `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM`, not both. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE). This is the most likely source of your difficulty — you are trying to do something that is not documented to work.

Third, `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+, if your app has a `targetSdkVersion` of 24 or higher. You will need to use `FileProvider` or some similar solution.

Comment: Today, I checked the Whatsapp application and the application can send email with multiple attachments and email body. Do you know how this is possible even if the official Android documents says that it is not possible.

Comment: @NimeshChandramaniya: Some email apps might support it. No email app *has* to support it. And it is undocumented exactly what it takes to support it. Maybe the email app that you are trying is expecting a single `String` for `EXTRA_TEXT` instead of an `ArrayList<CharSequence>`. On the ~2 billion Android devices and ~10,000 device models, there are dozens, if not hundreds, of email clients. Their behavior will vary widely.